# importing subgroup information in multi-comics analysis

Tags: cytoscape

I am following the activepathways vignettes. And I am trying to visualize the multi-omics data.

I can not seem to input the style.In Cytoscape, the iamge/chart1 is not working when I select column "instruct" and Mapping Type "Passthrough mapping".

Comment: What is activepathways? Can you link to the app or tutorial you are referring to so we can attempt to follow.

Comment: https://github.com/reimandlab/ActivePathways this is the tutorial